# Cutefish OS not booting

Tags: boot

I was trying to install cutefish OS on my laptop. It gets stuck on a black screen while trying to boot. [image: image here]

Comment: Try switching TTYs (CTRL+ALT+F1 to F7)

Comment: IMHO, that screen is _not_ black. Well, not blank in any case.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is easy. I’m the BIOS setup you must activate CSM or Legacy Support. That’s all. But, there is another booting issue apparently, I’m working on it.
Is related about the MBR and UEFI boot, apparently this option depending of your graphic card stuck the starting process of the desktop environment.

Comment: Please explain how “That’s all.” and “there is another ... issue” can be consistent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If this was the issue, surely the boot sequence would not get as far as it evidently gets?